# How can I use image title and image alt both?

Tags: jquery, fancybox

```
$("a.img").click(function(){
$.fancybox([{href:'images/img1.jpg', title: 'Sed elementum lorem purus, et hendrerit enim. Ut dignissim dolor eget ante gravida scelerisque. Suspendisse bibendum malesuada pharetra.'},{href:'images/img2.jpg', title: 'Aenean dictum volutpat magna ut posuere. Proin nec diam mi.'}], {
          openEffect:'none',
          closeEffect:'none',
          helpers:{
               title:{
                    type:'inside'
               }
          },
          closeBtn:false
     });
return false;
});
```

I'm using title for each image but at the same time I want to a text (with alt or another way) for a category. This title text show bottom of images in fancybox gallery view . If I can use the alt attribute for category I think use this top of the images.

Comment: "alt" attribute is used an alternate text for an image, if the image cannot be displayed, so why would you need that as display...!

Comment: it is so clear i'll use the title for image description and use the alt for image category name.

Answer (score 0):

Use the attr() method..

For more details check out the following link:
http://api.jquery.com/attr/

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `HTML5 DOCTYPE`, then you could use the `data-*` attributte for that purpose like

```
<a class="img" title="my title" data-category="image category name"><img src="thumb.jpg" alt="alternate" /></a>
```

... then use the `beforeShow` API option to construct the title like

```
beforeShow : function(){
 this.title = this.title + " - Category: " + this.data("category");
}
```

The only issue is that you would have to use both inside the `title`

.... or you may use the same `beforeShow` option to append any HTML like

```
'<span class="category">'+this.data("category")+'</span>'
```

to the `.fancybox-inner` selector though and then use `afterClose` option to remove it.